# FastAPI Depends use-case application

Tags: python, dependency-injection, dependencies, fastapi, depends

Let's consider the following code

```
class CommonDependency:
    ...


@app.on_event("startup")
async def start():
    parser = ArgumentParser(...)
    ... # here dep are init with command line arguments
    return dep

@app.get("/")
async def root(dep = Depends(start)):
    ... # here dep is needed
    return ...
```

The `start` function needs to be run at startup because it will make use of command line arguments in order to create the dependencies.

The problem is that `dep` is some stateful object that should share its state across all requests since boot.

The solution is declare `dep` in the module scope

```
dep = CommonDependency(...)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def start():
   dep.property = ... # here the property contains the init dependency that we need
```

and overwrite a property declared inside the class to be accessed through all the module functions.

However, doing that, `Depends` became useless because the `dep` object is visible by all functions.

I really don't like this approach, is there any better solution?

Comment: You can store it in app state that accessible via `request.app` https://www.starlette.io/applications/#storing-state-on-the-app-instance

Comment: So is there no alternatives for stateful objects?

Comment: IMO, Python's duck typing eliminates the need for a dependency injection" concept (as defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

I also think that this "Depends" mechanics is just masking a global callable. I am new to FastAPI, so maybe there is some extra handling for making async calls, who knows.

Comment: Just found this answer which explains why Depends is needed in FastAPI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810270/7373966